# Calling picturePanel_Paint event handler

Tags: vb.net

I have this `event handler` in `Mainform.vb`:

```
Private Sub picturePanel_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles picturePanel.Paint
    If fBitmap IsNot Nothing Then
        g = picturePanel.CreateGraphics()
        g.DrawImage(fBitmap, 0, 0)
        g.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

From a private method `updateView` in `Mainform.vb` I'm trying to call this handler but a little unsure of the parameters - I assume the first is just `Me.picturePanel` and the second parameter must be something in connection with `PaintEventArgs`

```
Private Sub updateView()
    'picturePanel.Refresh() '<<<<<<<<<this is fine but thought the following might work...
    picturePanel_Paint(Me.picturePanel, PaintEventArgs)
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

The following attempt at calling the event manually is failing:

[image]

Comment: why do you want to call it manually?

Comment: `Refresh` is the correct way of doing it but surely I can manually call the event - just want to know out of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not use the `sender/e` objects in that `picture box's paint event`, so that, there will be no problem(nothing will affect your code) by calling it manually. If you call it manually then it'll be like a simple `procedure` call.

Use the follwing snippet to achieve your result,

```
call picturePanel_Paint(New Object,New PaintEventArgs)
```

**Note:**

- It is not a good practice at all, .refresh() will also call the same.
- `sender/e` will be nothing if you did not set its property manually
  during a manual call.

**EDIT:** `Summary(Bug Fixed and New solution added)`

You can call the paint event like this to avoid your error as you mentioned in the comment,

```
call picturePanel_Paint(New Object, New PaintEventArgs(picturePanel.CreateGraphics, New Rectangle))
```

**But the following way of coding will be a clean way to match your requirement,**

```
Private Sub picturePanel_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles picturePanel.Paint
   call PerformSomething()
End Sub

private sub PerformSomething()
  'Your code Here
End Sub
```

Call the `procedure PerformSomething` where ever you want to call the `paint event`.

Comment: +1 thanks for the solution - and warnings! - best I stick to `ReFresh`

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I've amended the OP with result of this implementation

Comment: yes - I've added an Edit/screenprint of the error in the Original Post - any idea how to fix this? Seems like `New PaintEventArgs` is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

There is no object ready to pass as `PaintEventArgs` to the `picturePanel_Paint` event handler. If you really want to call this event handler manually, you will have to create the new PaintEventArgs object and fill it's properties with proper data, which is not an easy task

Comment: +1 thanks - good to know that sometimes it's quite a trivial operation calling an event procedure but sometimes, like here, it is non-trial !